# Saving/loading a table (with different column lengths) using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

A bit of context: I am writting a code to save the data I plot to a text file. This data should be stored in such a way it can be loaded back using a script so it can be displayed again (but this time without performing any calculation). The initial idea was to store the data in columns with a format x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3...

I am using a code which would be simplified to something like this (incidentally, I am not sure if using a list to group my arrays is the most efficient approach):

```
import numpy as np

MatrixResults = []

x1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
y1 = np.array([7,8,9,10,11,12])

x2 = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y2 = np.array([0,1,4,9])

MatrixResults.append(x1)
MatrixResults.append(y1)
MatrixResults.append(x2)
MatrixResults.append(y2)

MatrixResults = np.array(MatrixResults)

TextFile = open('/Users/UserName/Desktop/Datalog.txt',"w")

np.savetxt(TextFile, np.transpose(MatrixResults))

TextFile.close()
```

However, this code gives and error when any of the data sets have different lengths. Reading similar questions:

[Can numpy.savetxt be used on N-dimensional ndarrays with N>2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495777/can-numpy-savetxt-be-used-on-n-dimensional-ndarrays-with-n2)

[Table, with the different length of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670840/table-with-the-different-length-of-columns)

However, this requires to break the format (either with flattening or adding some filling strings to the shorter columns to fill the shorter arrays)

My issue summarises as:

1) Is there any method that at the same time we transpose the arrays these are saved individually as consecutive columns?

2) Or maybe is there anyway to append columns to a text file (given a certain number of rows and columns to skip)

3) Should  I try this with another library such as pandas?

Thank you very for any advice.

Edit 1:

After looking a bit more it seems that leaving blank spaces is more innefficient than filling the lists.

In the end I wrote my own (not sure if there is numpy function for this) in which I match the arrays length with "nan" values.

To get the data back I use the genfromtxt method and then I use this line:

x = x[~isnan(x)]

To remove the these cells from the arrays

If I find a better solution I will post it :)

Comment: Unless you really need to save the data in a text file, you could use `np.savez()` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html).

Answer (score 0):

To save your array you can use `np.savez` and read them back with `np.load`:

```
# Write to file
np.savez(filename, matrixResults)

# Read back
matrixResults = np.load(filename + '.npz').items[0][1]
```

As a side note you should follow naming conventions i.e. only class names start with upper case letters.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply (and recommendation) for the time  being I need to work with text file since I am not only saving the plot data but also more information (but in the future I might need to change to another format)